# How should I control audio volume in Cinnamon on Debian Buster / Devuan Beowulf?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, devuan, pulseaudio-equalizer

I've made a clean installation of Devuan ASCII and upgraded to Beowulf. I've logged in to Cinnamon, and things seem fine - except for controlling audio:

- There is no mixer up in the Start Menu by default
- If you install `alsamixergui` - it does nothing (not even complain)
- If you instead `pavucontrol`- you'll get the PusleAduio Volumne Control entry; but it will only tell you "Establishing connection to PulseAudio".
- If you manually start pulseaudio in a terminal - pavucontrol will work, but that's no way of doing things... also, it will show a "dummy" output device.
- When starting pulseaudio manually, it says:

  ```
  E: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.
  AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call",  sender=
  ":1.121" (uid=1000 pid=9019 comm="pulseaudio ") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.
  ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" 
  destination="org.bluez" (uid=0 pid=1972 comm="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd ")
  ```
- No volume control widget/applet on the taskbar

My question:

1. Is this my fault for not having installed something critical?
2. What can I do to resolve/circumnavigate around these this;

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you have two problems here

1. **Something is wrong with your config**

   1.1. Sound card is not recognized

> - *If you install alsamixergui - it does nothing (not even complain)*
> - *If you manually start pulseaudio in a terminal - pavucontrol will work, but that's no way of doing things... also, it will show a "dummy" output device.*

Seems that your sound card is not properly configured. Probably missing kernel modules. Search for *"Alsa sound card not detected"*.

This is the firts problem to fix. Once fixed use `alsamixer` to check that sound card is working properly.

1.2. Access to bluetooth devices not allowed

```
E: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.
AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call",  sender=
":1.121" (uid=1000 pid=9019 comm="pulseaudio ") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.
ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" 
destination="org.bluez" (uid=0 pid=1972 comm="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd ")
```

Seems that access to bluetooth is denied for your user. Are your user member of `bluetooth` group?

2. **Pulseaudio is not started automatically**

To fix this edit `/etc/pulse/client.conf.d/00-disable-autospawn.conf` and comment the line:

`autospawn=no`

See https://bugs.devuan.org//cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=318

Hope this helps

Comment: How is the link related to my issue?

Comment: This solved the problem in my computer. Upgrading from ascii to beowulf (xfce).  In my case 00-disable-autospawn.conf setting prevented pulseaudio to run before Xsession on non systemd systems.

Comment: You mean, when you did this, and started PulseAudio manually, you stopped getting the error message?

Answer (score 0):

no, that did not help.  Here's what worked for me (Devuan, Beowulf)

1. sudo gedit /etc/pulse/client.conf
2. remove semicolon in front of line about autospawn
3. save

Comment: What is "that"?